# Merge [tensorflow-js] and [tensorflow.js] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The two tags [tensorflow-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow-js) and [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) tag
 clearly designates the JS API for tensorflow. There should be only one tag instead of two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, both of them point to the same thing. From the tag wikis:

- [tensorflow-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow-js)

  > > TensorFlow.js is a WebGL accelerated, browser based JavaScript library
  > >     for training and deploying machine learning models.
  >
  > TensorFlow.js is a [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl) accelerated, browser-based
  >   [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) library for training and deploying machine learning
  >   models, based on [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow).
  >
  > References:
  >
  > - [Official homepage](https://js.tensorflow.org/)
  > - [GitHub page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs)
- [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js)

  > > A WebGL accelerated, browser based JavaScript library for training and
  > >     deploying ML models.
  >
  > #### Definition:
  >
  > [TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/) is a WebGL accelerated, browser based JavaScript
  >   library for training and deploying ML models.
  >
  > #### Important Links:
  >
  > - [Official TensorFlow.js Home Page](https://js.tensorflow.org/)
  > - [TensorFlow.js Tutorials and Guides](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/)
  > - [TensorFlow.js API Reference](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/)
  > - [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs)
  > - [TensorFlow.js (NPM)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs)
  >
  > #### Related Tags:
  >
  > [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) [neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neural-network)

I've merged both and kept the [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) tag as the master, as the [official name for the JS APIs is tensorflow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/).

Some stats from the merge:

```
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, new count: 118
tag remapping of [tensorflow.js] and [tensorflow-js] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
24 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym tensorflow-js -> tensorflow.js was approved!
```

Comment: Thanks for merging both tags into one. It will be easier to help when there is one tag than to have to check for questions on both tags