# Synonymise [tensorflowjs] with [tensorflow.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [tensorflowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflowjs) and [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) designates the JS API for TensorFlow. There should be only one tag instead of two.

Comment: [Previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372724/merge-tensorflow-js-and-tensorflow-js-tags) [tensorflow-js] was merged into [tensorflow.js]

Comment: It's strange that [tensorflowjs] could be created in the first place (created 1 month ago). Shouldn't the system have blocked it because it's so similar to an existing tag?

Comment: Definitely that's a good question. I am puzzled as well to see this new tag

Answer (score 2):

That makes sense, yes, and done. The tag has been synonymized in this direction:

[tensorflowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflowjs) (× 23)   → [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) (× 394).

What doesn't make much sense is that the tag itself could be created. As Stijn mentions, we already have a system that prevents users from creating version specific tags, or plurals of existing tags or hyphenated versions of existing tags. Looks like this is a nice loop hole that we have found.