# Why is "0 questions" in the tags page actually over 1024 questions?

Tags: bug, tags

If you go to [the 1666th tags page on the popular tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1666&tab=popular), and scroll down, you can see the [tensorflow-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow-js) tag is the first question with seemingly 0 questions.  But when you go to [[tensorflow-js]'s page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js?tab=Newest), you can see it has over 1024 questions (1026 at the time of writing).  Why is it like this?

Comment: @JeanneDark : Thank you for helping me notice that!  It's just that it is confusing as to why they still have [tag:tensorflow-js] (note the '-') as a tag in the tags page when [tag:tensorflow.js] has already been marked as the one that stays.

Comment: What a silly issue...I realize that it's a bug of some description but honestly, when was the last time anyone went to the 3rd page of Google search results, let alone the 1,666th page of Stack Overflow's search results?

Comment: @Makoto : I was trying to find the first tag in Stack Overflow that had no questions, that's why.  I just noticed how far I went.  Note that I started at the end and kept going until I found the page, I didn't start from page 1 :)

Comment: You could have just used data.stackexchange.com, which probably automatically accounts for tag synonyms.

Comment: @LakshyaRaj Tags with no questions automatically get deleted by the system, so the only ones you're going to find are ones that just had their last question removed (so the system hasn't deleted it yet) or synonyms like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[tensorflow-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow-js) is a tag synonym of [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) and they have been merged.

See the MSE FAQ [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718)

> The system organizes tags in a master–synonym relationship. All attempts to use the synonym tag for any given master tag are automatically converted to the master tag. So, users can enter a synonym tag when writing a question, but the master tag will be displayed when the question is loaded.

The tags were then merged:

> This retags all questions tagged with another tag – which is not automatically done when a synonym is created. [...]

> Merging, by itself, does not create a synonym, meaning that the tag that was merged can be recreated and used later. In most cases, you will want to create or ensure that a synonym exists, so that future attempts to use the merged tag will replace it with the canonical tag instead.

In this case, both tags existed but since they mean the very same thing, user decided to merge these two tags and [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) became the master. That's why all those questions are shown with [tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow.js) but the other tag still exists.

Here's a link to that discussion: [Merge [tensorflow-js] and [tensorflow.js] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372724/11682469)